# Can't Find and Open Dll when Call in C++

Tags: c++, dll

i have one problem with use the dll's in my c++ project ! (My Code Blow):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

typedef const char* (WINAPI* AvLicens)(void);


int main()
{
  HMODULE Loadme;
  Loadme = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\avcodec.dll");

  if (NULL != Loadme)
 {
    std::cout << "Loaded.";
    AvLicens func = (AvLicens)GetProcAddress(Loadme, "avcodec_license");
    if (func != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: \n" << func << std::endl;
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "// Error: Can not Open '" << Loadme << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

My problem is: Can't Find the avcodec.dll ! actually i want to call avcodec_license from avcodec.dll. i tested this for another dlls but same problem showing me. (jump to else section)

Thank you

Comment: You should be calling `GetLastError` if the call to `LoadLibrary` fails.

Comment: there are many reasons why it's not opening. Have you tried loading the DLL in "dependency walker"?

Comment: Are the dll's in your PATH? In your application directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) didn't give you an idea why your library could not be loaded and if `GetLastError` code also didn't help, you can use internal trace log available for `LoadLibrary`.

It's pretty advanced functionality and it requires you to get `gflags.exe` utility. It's part of *[Debugging Tools for Windows](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit)*. To enable logging run the following command:

```
gflags.exe -i YouProject.exe +sls
```

After that run your application in debugger to see the trace log output.

Comment: i have already the 'Debugging Tools for Windows' and run the following command: gflags.exe -i MyProject.exe +sls .
and enable exception logging from settings. but where logs saved?

Comment: @Sina Run app in debugger. If you are using Visual Studio, log will be visible in Debugger Output view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys...

I Just Change the Debug cfg from x64 to x86 and the function name 'avcodec_license' i didn't see in the dll source and changed to 'avcodec_version' ! whatever ... it's worked ! thank you for sharing your exprience with me.

Be good :)